# HTML5 section footer inherits footer style

Tags: html, css

I'm building WEB with HTML5 for the first time and I encountered with the little problem.

I have code:

```
<header></header>

<section>
<header></header>
<article></article>
<footer></footer>
</section>

<footer></footer>
```

and the problem is, that my Section footer inherits my footer style. i don't know how to remove inheritance from my code. Can you help me?

P.S.: my section footer inherits footer style, not footer. There is a photo: [link to photo](http://s22.postimg.org/7hze41bm9/Be_pavadinimo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an ID or CLASS to your section footer or style the section footer like:
     section > footer { }

However that may not work in all browsers and is somewhat sloppy. I would just add an ID or CLASS.

Comment: yes, I thought that, but I also want fully HTML5 code without unnecessary divs

Comment: I am pretty sure you can add a class to <footer>, give it a shot.

Comment: problem will not be solved, coz my footer have 100% width and fixed height but <section> footer don't have it, it have only 50% width and auto height... but thanks, i will try with it :)

Comment: Give each footer a different class and then style them. Like <footer class="main"> and style footer.main { } and <footer class ="section"> and style footer.section { }. Now I do not use HTML5 really, I do a lot more PHP and JavaScript coding, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew is right just add a class to footer or make style: 'section > footer{}'  or 'body > footer{}'